# Variance definition

Tags: self-study, distributions, variance, cumulative-distribution-function, moments

How can I show that these two expressions are the same.

$$\int_0^1\int_0^xF(z)dzdx \le \int_0^1\int_0^xG(z)dzdx$$
$$\iff$$
$$\text{var}_F(x)\le \text{var}_G(x)$$
where F and G are distribution functions with support [0,1] and the same mean.

I am stuck with taking integral and the definition of variance.

Comment: Are you sure you have correctly formulated the equations? Why would this be true? Consider constant $0$ vs.  uniform over $[0,1]$

Comment: Yes sure. F and G with support [0,1]. @JuhoKokkala

Comment: There must be a typographical error. After all, if you take any two distributions $F$ and $G$ supported on the interval $(1,\infty)$, then both of these double integrals are zero, the inequality is true, but it doesn't tell you a thing about the variances. If indeed the support is assumed to be $[0,1]$, then it is essential that you edit your post to state that.  If you then integrate by parts, the result should be apparent.

Comment: Yes I stated. I added the support between  0 and 1 interval. @whuber can you show how can I show it? The way on my mind is to use definition of variance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A first integration leads to$$\int_0^1 \int_0^x F(z)\text{d}z\,\text{d}x=\int_0^1 \int_0^1\mathbb{I}_{z\le x} F(z)\text{d}z\,\text{d}x=\int_0^1 \int_z^1 F(z)\text{d}x\,\text{d}z=\int_0^1 (1-z) F(z)\text{d}z$$
Now, mean and variance of the distribution $F$ can be associated with the cdf $F$ as$$\mathbb{E}^F[X]=\int_0^1 x\text{d}F(x)=\int_0^1 (1-F(x))\text{d}x$$and$$\mathbb{E}^F[X^2]=\int_0^1 x^2\text{d}F(x)=2\int_0^1 x(1-F(x))\text{d}x=1-2\int_0^1 xF(x)\text{d}x$$Hence
\begin{align*}\int_0^1 (1-z) F(z)\text{d}z&=1-\int_0^1(1-F(x))\text{d}x - \int_0^1 z F(z)\text{d}z\\
&=1-\mathbb{E}^F[X]-\frac{1}{2}\{1-\mathbb{E}^F[X^2] \}\\
&=\frac{1}{2}-\mathbb{E}^F[X]+\frac{1}{2}\mathbb{E}^F[X^2]\\
&\le\frac{1}{2}-\mathbb{E}^G[X]+\frac{1}{2}\mathbb{E}^G[X^2] \end{align*}
**Q.E.D.**

Comment: +1.  A little simpler, perhaps, is to invoke Fubini to observe $$\eqalign{\int_0^1\int_0^xF(z)dzdx&=\int_0^1\int_0^x\int_0^zdF(t)dzdx\\&=\int_0^1dF(t)\int_t^1dz\int_z^1dx\\&= \int_0^1\left(\frac{1}{2}-t+\frac{t^2}{2}\right)dF(t).}$$

Comment: I have a question on a term. in the first line and second integral. Inside this integral, what is the meaning of  the first term like $I_{z\le x}$. Thank you for your answer:)

Comment: I asked this term $\mathbb{I}_{z\le x}$ ? Is it identity matrix?

Comment: I hope you have sorted out by now that there is no matrix involved here : $\mathbb{I}_{z\le x}$ denotes the _indicator function_ that takes values 1 and 0, depending on whether or not $z\le x$.